# Is there a way to do calculations in GNU parallel using its inputs?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I am using GNU parallel on linux and I wanted to do some calculations in it, but I can't get it to substitute the inputs.

Starting with this, that works fine:

```
parallel echo {1} {2} ::: {1..2} ::: {1..2}
```

Output:

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
parallel echo {1} $(({2} *2)) ::: {1..2} ::: {1..2}
```

But all I get is:

```
bash: {2} * 2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{2} * 2")
```

I tried using `expr`, but the problem was the same, the second parameter does not get substituted:

```
parallel echo {1} $(expr {2} \* 2 ) ::: {1..2} ::: {1..2}
expr: non-integer argument
1
1
2
2
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parallel echo {1} '{=1 $_=$arg[2]*2 =}' ::: {1..2} ::: {1..2}
```

You are not limited to computing using a single argument:

```
parallel echo {1} '{=1 $_=$arg[1]/$arg[2] =}' ::: {1..2} ::: {1..2}
```

If you prefer to do it in shell you just need to quote it:

```
parallel echo {1} '$(expr {2} \* 2 )' ::: {1..2} ::: {1..2}
```

Comment: Using your first suggestion all I get are outputs like this: `1 {=1 /usr/bin/parallel=[2]*2 =}`

Comment: I noticed my version of parallel was not very up to date, I updated it to version 20170322, and now it works just fine. Thanks!